# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO table multiple records taken from multiple selects

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, cross-join, sql-returning

I have these 3 tables

recipe: `recipe_id | name`

ingredient: `ingredient_id | name`

recipes_ingredients: `id | recipe_id | ingredient_id`

The first id of every table is a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` and the two names are `character varying(50)`. I'm trying to insert`recipe_id` and `ingredient_id` in `recipes_ingredients` and if I do it with a single ingredient it works perfectly. The problem is that I don't know how to insert multiple ingredient associated with a single recipe.

This is what I tried to insert 3 different ingredients associated with the same recipe:

```
BEGIN;
WITH new_recipe AS (
    INSERT INTO recipe (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING recipe_id
), ingredient1 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
), ingredient2 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
), ingredient3 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
)
INSERT INTO recipes_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) 
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient1.ingredient_id FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient1,
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient2.ingredient_id  FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient2,
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient3.ingredient_id  FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient3
COMMIT;
```

It gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 13: SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient2.ingredient_id  FROM...
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 520
```

Comment: The syntax for cross joins is: `from table_one cross join table_two cross join table_three ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `,`  with a `union/union all` after each select

```
BEGIN;
WITH new_recipe AS (
    INSERT INTO recipe (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING recipe_id
), ingredient1 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
), ingredient2 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
), ingredient3 AS (
    INSERT INTO ingredient (name) VALUES ('{}') RETURNING ingredient_id
)
INSERT INTO recipes_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) 
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient1.ingredient_id FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient1 Union
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient2.ingredient_id  FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient2 Union
SELECT new_recipe.recipe_id, ingredient3.ingredient_id  FROM new_recipe CROSS JOIN ingredient3;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: have you tested this? My guess is that UNION would work. But with ; only the first CTE insert would trigger.

Comment: Yeah my bad `Union` would work no semicolon just realized you had used CTE if you want you can have seperate CTEs either way union would be better choice and can leave the last semicolon before commit

Comment: I wonder, would there be a difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` if CTE's are used like this. *(first time I've seen it on SO)* ... Never mind, it'll just make a difference in the output. Unique id's with union.

Comment: It works with the UNION. Thanks!!